# How can reassing a keyboard key on debian linux?

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I am using kali linux, xfce desktop is installed. I want to change the functionality of the circled key on the image. Even though that key shows "" for some reason it types "<".

[image]

As a programmer, I use "right arrow key" very often so I want to assign the circled key to "right arrow key",because in the current layout, "right arrow key" is far to reach so it slows me down typing.

So I will have two "right arrow keys", I tried to create shortcut with keyboard settings, but it says "right is already assigned. DO you wanna use < instead". Since i don't use the circled key for "<" character, I wanna assign it to "right" to I can use it with my thump easily.

This is msi laptop, msi has steel-steer-3 app for macos and windows but not for linux

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question with this command:

```
 xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = KP_Right"
```